# Customize Toast like closed page in chrome android

Tags: android, toast

I want like this:

[image]

When I close the page, appear.

[image]

After some seconds, disappear.
It's a `Toast`? Or a layout? How can I do that?

Comment: Do you need it to be interactive? If not just shoot off a toast from a service or something.

Comment: Yes, that's why it's not (enough) good for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE:** [Snackbars are now in the Support Design Library version 22.2.0](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html)

Those are officially called [Snackbars](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html#). They are not in the SDK (yet) but there is an implementation on [GitHub](https://github.com/nispok/snackbar).

Comment: Yes, exactly  that I want! Thank you! :)

Comment: Just out of interest since the topic was brought up, has anyone heard when this might be included in the native framework? This is something that I am sure a lot of us could have made use of in past projects.

Comment: No idea. I wouldn't be surprised if Google decided not to add it since it is not complicated to implement. Though it would be convenient to show a snackbar with one line of code just like toasts.